# WCF Test Client EndPoint error

Tags: c#, wcf

IN my WCF Service, the WCF Test Client reports the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].
```

My App.Config is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<services>
  <service name="Practicon.SAPServiceLibrary.SAPDownloadService" behaviorConfiguration="debug">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8082/SAPDownloadService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Practicon.SAPServiceLibrary.ISAPDownloadService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <!--add baseAddress="http://localhost:8083/Design_Time_Addresses/Practicon/SAPServiceLibrary/SAPDownloadService/"/> -->
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8082/SAPDownloadService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="debug">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <!--<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>-->
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<client>
  <endpoint name="PracticonSAPDownloadEndPointClient"
            address="net.tcp://localhost:8082/SAPDownloadService"
            binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BindingConfiguration"
            contract="Practicon.SAPServiceLibrary.ISAPDownloadService">
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value=""/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>

<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="BindingConfiguration"
             transferMode="Buffered"/>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I have got a net.tcp Endpoint - the Service runs fine, just that this error is reported in the WCF Hosting.

Can someone explain what I've done wrong and how to correct it?

Thanks

MM

Comment: The app.config wcfTestClient uses is different to that from your client application - is the one above the one from the actual test client?

Comment: where is your wcf servie running? self-hosted or iis?

Comment: Thanks for comments. It's the standard WCFTestClient.exe. "Error" is shown in the "Status" column. My own server/client apps work lovely. Would just like nail the annoying error in the MSDN WCFTestClient.exe

Comment: As far as hosting is concerned, it is/will always be self-hosting.

Comment: Have you checked the config file in the "My Service Projects" pane?  When I use the test client the config is totally different from my client one.